# JDBC PreparedStatement SELECT Error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Tengo este pedazo de código que declara un prepareStatement y lo debería ejecutar para obtener un dato de mi DB.

```
        String getIdCons= "SELECT id_consulta FROM `consulta` WHERE id_paciente=? ;";
        PreparedStatement consId = ConnectToDentDB.getConnection().prepareStatement(getIdCons);
        consId.setInt(1,id_pac);
        ResultSet idCons = consId.executeQuery(getIdCons);

        if(idCons.next()){

            id_consulta = idCons.getInt(1);
        }

        consId.close();
        idCons.close();
```

Pero me está arrojando este error:

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

Sé que es un error de sintaxis en el query "SELECT id_consulta FROM `consulta` WHERE id_paciente=? ;", pero no logro descubrir cuál es.

¿Alguien podría darme una idea de lo que pudiera ser?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes omitir el punto y coma , preferentemente puedes escribir `consulta` sólo consulta.

He construido un snippet que puede ayudarte:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        int idPac = 1;
        int idConsulta = 0;
        String consulta = "select id_consulta from consulta where id_paciente = ?";
        Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/demo", "postgres", "example");
        PreparedStatement sentencia = conexion.prepareStatement(consulta);
        sentencia.setInt(1, idPac);
        ResultSet idCons = sentencia.executeQuery();
        if ( idCons.next() ) {
            idConsulta = idCons.getInt("id_consulta");
        }
        System.out.println(idConsulta);
        sentencia.close();
        conexion.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Something happens wrong" + e.toString());
    } 
}
```

Te daré una lista de temas importantes que considero puedes checar para escribir mejor código :

- Try with resources
- Ciclos ( for , while , do while ) sobre todo por que deberías tener varias consultas por paciente, pero depende de cómo hayas modealado tu BD.
- Recuerda que en el nombrado de java utilizamos lower camel case para variables y upper camel para las clases.

Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, Eduardo! El error era precisamente que estaba metiendo el string del query como parámetro en el executeQuery(). Gracias por tus recomendaciones también. Excelente día.

Comment: nada que agradecer , es todo un placer :D